# How do I model a Gömböc?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How do I model a [Gömböc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6mb%C3%B6c)? Specifically, would I start with a primitive, like a sphere, and cut it down? How would I cut with the mathematical proportions in mind?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Quite complex shape ... here is one for free to download if you don't mind https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1985100 in edit mode you can see topology of the mesh, that can help you to understand how it was made.